# Which of the following holds? Problem in group theory.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group whose presentation is

$G=\{x,y\mid x^5=y^2=e, x^2y=yx\}$

Then $G$ is isomorphic to

1) $\mathbb Z_5$

2) $\mathbb Z_{10}$

3) $\mathbb Z_2$

4) $\mathbb Z_{30}$

I thought that clealy it is only isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{10}$. But then i am confused with the given relator? Where i am wrong?

Comment: You can quickly rule out $\mathbb Z_5$ because none of its members except $e$ satisfies $y^2=e$ and $Z_2$ because none of its members except $e$ satisfies $x^5=e$. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes and also $\mathbb Z_{30}$

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{30}$ does have members other than $e$ satisfying those two equations. $\qquad$

Comment: But then i think no of elements here in this group are not $30$. can i say that?

Comment: I am surprised with answer. It is $\mathbb Z_2$

Comment: What makes you think it is $\mathbb Z_2$? $\qquad$

Comment: it is given in the answer key of exam. But I am still very much confused that how is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captain Lama's answer is obviously much more comprehensive. But if you want to know how to game the multiple-choice system, read on!

If we're convinced that *one* of the choices is correct, we can assume that $x$ and $y$ commute. We can do that because all choices are Abelian, hence $xy = yx$ no matter which the group ends up being.

But this means that, since $x^2y = yx$, we have

\begin{align*}
x^2y &= yx \tag{given}\\
x^2y &= xy \tag{commutativity}\\
x^2 &= x \tag{$y^{-1}$ on the right}\\
x &=1. \tag{multiply by $x^{-1}$}
\end{align*}

Thus we can safely throw $x$ out of the generating set, as well as any relation involving $x$, in this case. Then your group is $\langle y \mid y^2 = e\rangle$, clearly $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: i am more satisfied with your answer because captain lama way is bit more useful if we know the answer. But i like  your approach more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have $y^{2}xy^{-2} = y(yxy^{-1})y^{-1} = yx^2y^{-1} = (yxy^{-1})^2 = x^4$. But $y^2 = e$ so $y^{2}xy^{-2} = x$. All in all, $x^3 = e$ and since $x^5 = e$, $x=e$.

So the only generator is $y$, and is of order $2$ : your group is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You got there before I did. :)

Comment: $ I got it. But if i don't know the answer how to proceed for the problem?

Comment: A good rule of thumb in these situations is to look at conjugation actions : here one of the relations gives you the action of $y$ by conjugation ; it sends $x$ to $x^2$. Once you notice that, combined with the fact that conjugation by $y$ must be of order $2$, the proof is easy to find.

Comment: @Captain Lama thanks sir